# Получить сообщение об ошибке, отправленное с сервера

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

На сервер через Axios передаются данные, в случае ошибки при проверке на сервере в ответ отправляется следующие сообщение:

```
 new ResponseEntity<String>(exception.getMessage(), HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
```

Соответственно, при обработке ответ попадает в catch(err), но не получается получить из него сообщение (exception.getMessage()), хотя в браузере, в ответе, который приходит, я это сообщение вижу. Если я вызываю err.name, то получаю "Error", если err.message, то получаю `Request failed with status code 403`.

Как мне получить сообщение которое было отправлено с сервера?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение:

```
 error.response.data
```